# Getting syntax error while using fopen and fread

Tags: php

```
$file = "status.txt";
$open = fopen($file, "r");
$size = filesize($file);
$count = fread($open, $size);

if($count == 1) {
    header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
} else {
    echo "Status is unavailable";
}
```

Hello, I am trying to read a text file.
I get the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING` while doing this.
I am trying to read status.txt and if it has 1 it will redirect else it will say Status is unavailable.
Any ideas?

Comment: On what line is the unexpected T_STRING?

Comment: Which line throws that error message?

Comment: There must be something wrong with your syntax, please can you tell the specific line and it's content? By the way: Use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) to read out a file. Much more easier.

Comment: It's line 4. $open = fopen($file, "r");
$size = filesize($file);
$count = fread($open, $size);
. The error is there with those 3 lines. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried it with a test file, it works like a charm. Are you really sure that's all?

Comment: Btw the parser sometimes refer to a line that's unrelated, the error must be in the lines before..

Comment: Did you forget to close a statement with a semicolon?

Comment: @DanLee the error will be missing semicolon on the line that follows.

Answer (score 0):

I must point out that for simple files like this, that [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is much easier than `fopen`, `fread`, `fclose` (which you omitted), etc.

The code that you posted does not appear to have any issues by itself. Perhaps you messed something up before that whole block? Try and comment things out to isolat the bug. This is a debugging skill you will need to acquire.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in those lines for sure! please include the whole PHP script, there're must be something wrong before or after those lines.

Please try this code out!

```
<?php

    $file = 'status.txt';
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    if ((strlen($contents)-1) == 1) {
        header('Location: http://www.google.com');
    } else {
        echo 'Status is unavailable';
    }

?>
```

The (-1) in the compression because of the new line character count at the last line.

Comment: That is the whole php script. There is nothing else.

Comment: please upload the file(same as you have) somewhere and provide a link.

Comment: @JohnMcCain please try this out!

Answer (score -1):

If you're talking about the content of "status.txt" please put the '1' between quotes. if it is just a TRUE or FALSE statement just use if($count){ ... }else{ ...}

Comment: Im facing trouble with 
$open = fopen($file, "r");
$size = filesize($file);
$count = fread($open, $size); . It keeps giving me T_STRING error.

Comment: From the php-documentation:
_When reading from anything that is not a regular local file, such as streams returned when reading remote files or from popen() and fsockopen(), reading will stop after a packet is available. 

This means that you should collect the data together in chunks.
Try:
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "rb");
$contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
fclose($handle);

Comment: @SebassvanBoxel it's not a must to enclose the 1 between single/double quotes, PHP will always juggle the types in comparisons, in that case both of the operands will be converted to a boolean, 1 is TRUE and if the $count variable not empty will be TRUE also.